# Touchgfx and NucleoH755 board and Riverdi screen initialization issue with black screen

Tags: embedded, stm32, microcontroller, stm, touchgfx

I have an H755 nucleo board and a riverdi 5'' rgb display.

After

- setting the ltdc ,
- the clock to 25mhz
- the freertos
- not using qspi and sdram just by using the 2 layer start address 0x20000000 and 0x20119400 for RGB888
- I have enabling the nvic
- I have crosscheck the riverdi example for the ltdc setup and the polarities and everything is the same.
- I have checked the +VLED and -VLED from the led driver it provides 12V and the rest of the system is on 3.3V.
- I have opened the touchgfx and set only one red box as background.
- I have set a blinking function to CM4 and to CM7 to be sure that all are working. Technically on CM7 the program runs i and inside the touchgfx freertos task it just opens the red led for some seconds and closes it again. After this it calls the touchgfx_process functions as it should.

The screen does not open.
If i am not using qspi and sdram do **i need to write something on how to send the data to the display pins**? **do i need to control something**?

here is a link to the project (zipped):[Example Project](https://mega.nz/file/XwUG0BjQ#jZBSwcrhRxUH8hSyd2uHPPcH0v_7nexolbOVuwo6Odg)
[image: Build Ram analysis]

**Based on this image what should have been the proper framebuffer Starting address for the board**?

official documentation
[Riverdi product page](https://riverdi.com/product/high-brightness-ips-display-rvt50hqtnwca0-5-inch-projected-capacitive-touch-panel-air-bonding-atouch-rgb)

[board user manual](https://file:///C:/Users/KyriakosPavlidis/Downloads/um2408-stm32h7-nucleo144-boards-mb1363-stmicroelectronics-1.pdf)

analysing the pins i see:
[image: pins1]
[image: pins2]

Comment: I think you're trying to do too much at once. Try just defining a framebuffer array, fill it with a pattern, and display that. Then worry about TouchGFX. (FYI I'm doing exactly that right now on a project I'm working on.)

Comment: Also note that your display contains a Sitronix ST7262 display controller. For sure you will need to configure some registers in that to enable the display, over I2C. You'll need to find the datasheet for that to learn more.

Comment: from what i check in the example project that they have in touchgfx they do not have anything else in the setup than the usual things.

Comment: based on st documentation ltdc handles the transfer of data to the screen but i am not sure about it.

Comment: the interface is RGB it does not have i2c pins for the display as you see the datasheet of the display. i2c is only for the capacitive touch

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you're right. There must be a micro on the display that does all that for you then, since the ST7262 definitely comes up in "sleep mode" and needs to be poked to turn on.

Comment: i have added some pins test if they can help

Comment: For what it's worth I just got the display in my project working properly. The missing part was setting the layer 0 Alpha constant to be 255 in CubeIDE. Without that I got a black screen. I'm not (yet) using TouchGFX. Just an array as a framebuffer that I configure my layer with `HAL_LTDC_SetAddress()` that I then fill with a pattern.

Comment: what size of screen and framebuffer did you use? cause the screen that i use is 800*480 and in the memory of the nucleo it does not fit

Comment: My screen is 320x240 with RGB888. So `(320 * 240 * 3)` bytes. The LTDC can do things like 1 byte per pixel with a colour lookup table, if you don't have enough SRAM.